# python 3: urllib, csv reader, and StringIO- why the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

These two approaches yield different results in python 3.7.3:

```
res = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
content = res.read().decode('utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(content))
lines = list(reader)
```

And

```
res = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
content = res.read().decode('utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(content)
lines = list(reader)
```

The former gives me what I want, a list of the rows from the CSV, the latter gives me a list containing lists of length 1 of single characters only (each character in the text is its own list), so:

```
Year,PID
2019,1
2018,2
```

And

```
Y
e
a
r,
P
i
d
(etc)
```

What's the difference?

Comment: iterating a file-like object yields lines. Iterating a string yields characters. CSV reader iterates the first arg, so the observed result is expected

Comment: In one case, you are passing a file-like object to the csv reader, which will give it what it expects: an iterator over *lines*. In the latter, you pass it a string, which will iterate over the individual characters

Comment: FWIW urllib has nothing do with your question: it's just returning some data as a string; where that string came from is irrelevant to the rest of your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO) implements [TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.TextIOBase) which is:

> in-memory stream for text I/O

- It's important to note [that](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#in-memory-streams):

> For strings StringIO can be used like a file opened in text mode

[csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader) treats `StringIO(content)` as open file. 
And `reader` is

> a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile

- So `lines = list(reader)` will return you a list of lines in `content`

In the second case `content` is of type string.

- So `csv.reader(content)` will return an iterator over the string.

And this is [because](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)  csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and
>   returns a string each time its **next**() method is called

- That's why `lines = list(reader)` returns a list of characters, as it treats each character in `content` as a row.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [documentation for `csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given *csvfile*. *csvfile* can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.

If you're not sure what "the iterator protocol" is, it's basically equivalent to what happens when you loop over some object in a for loop.  For example with a `list`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for item in l:
...     print(item)
1
2
3
```

That is, for `list`s the iterator protocol is implemented in the "obvious" way that it returns each element of the list in order.  For strings:

```
>>> s = 'row,from,csv'
>>> for char in s:
...     print(char)
...
r
o
w
,
f
r
o
m
,
c
s
v
```

For most "file-like" objects like StringIO the iterator protocol is defined such that each loop returns a single *line* of text (with the trailing newline):

```
>>> s = """\
... row,1
... row,2
... """
>>> b = StringIO(s)
>>> for line in b:
...     print(line)
...
row,1

row,2
```

So in the latter case it's treating a simple *string* as a sequence of one character "rows" from the CSV.